# Reveillark death trigger

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I control a [Reveillark](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reveillark) and a few other creatures of power 2 or less and my opponent uses [Wrath of God](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wrath%20of%20God), can I get back creatures that are dying to the wrath or do they have to have been in the graveyard before the wrath was cast? I'm unsure how the stack should work here

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily the stack that you need to figure out, it's triggered abilities and abilities resolving.

Here's what happens.

1. Opponent casts Wrath.
2. Wrath resolves, placing your creatures in the graveyard.
3. Reveillark's ability triggers. Since it and the other creatures are already in the graveyard, they are legal targets (well, not the Reveillark itself)
4. Reveillark's ability resolves, returning the other two creatures.